# How to make OR operator in regular expression?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

What i want is something like this:

```
(
[integer OR (ANY but not integer or white-space)]
[(ONE white-space OR NONE)]
[integer OR (ANY but not integer or white-space)]
)
```

Example of strings that will match: `99 $` `99$` `$ 99` `$99`

what i have now is two regular expression :

`^[^\d\s](\s{0,1})\d+` AND `^\d+(\s{0,1})[^\d\s]`

any ideas of how to replace those two with only one regular expression?

Comment: Do you only want to match them at the beginning of a string/line?

Comment: @stribizhev i want to match only the a like type of example i provided above.

Comment: Didn't [`|` alternatives](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) work for that simple regex?

Comment: See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/wN9nG9/1) just to warn \s match more than just whitespaces (it also match tabs, carriage return, line feed and newlines) for the rest use anchors and `|` as already said.

Comment: @mario didn't know about the pipe, and couldn't find on stackoverflow question as mine , but OK.

Comment: @Tensibai Thanks! do you know how to make it only for white-space ?

Comment: @ jimmy see the demo, I'm using a normal whitespace character: like this `A B` matched A whitespace B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to make a or in a regular expression is the pipe `|` ([ref](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/operator/pipe))

If you need to match one or the other of your regexp, you need to match `(A|B)` with A=`^[^\d\s](\s{0,1})\d+` and B=`^\d+(\s{0,1})[^\d\s]`

Result is `^(([^\d\s](\s{0,1})\d+)|(\d+(\s{0,1})[^\d\s]))`

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about the pipe :) i will accept this answer

Answer (score 1):

"|" is the "or" equivalent in regex. Group them and put | in between.

```
[^\d\s](\s{0,1})\d+|^\d+(\s{0,1})[^\d\s]
```

works just fine for your examples.

Answer (score 1):

```
^((?:\d+\s?[^\d\s]+)|(?:[^\d\s]+\s?\d+))$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hI0qP0/2

Comment: why did you change the expression? mine is not good enough or it's buggy? thanks

Comment: @Jimmy i added anchors so that partial matches dont happen.Also `\s{0,1}` is same as `\s?`